# rails deploy - database not uploading

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, deployment, cap

I'm working on my first rails app deploy and the database data from my local computer doesn't seem to be getting loaded into the database on the server when I deploy with capistrano. I'm not clear as to whether capistrano takes care of this or not. I have also tried running 'rake db:schema:load' from the /current release directory. Here's the log of what happens when I try to load the app (on the remote webserver) in a browser.

```
Started GET "/" for XX.XX.XX.XX at 2012-04-04 13:26:46 -0700
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Table 'project.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`):
  app/models/user.rb:61:in `authenticate_with_salt'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:50:in `user_from_remember_token'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
```

So the problem seems to be that the app loads, but the DB isn't populated with tables and data.

I'm sure I'm missing a relatively basic detail of the deployment process, but thus far it escapes me... Any help would be mucho appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `Capfile` look like?

Neither Rails nor Capistrano will copy data from your development environment to your deployment environment—`db:migrate:*` and `db:schema:*` only handle database structure. Before using `rake db:schema:load` make sure your development environment migrations have been run and your latest `db/schema.rb` is checked in to your repo.

If you want certain data to be in your database upon deployment look in `db/seeds.rb`. There are also [many gems](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=seed) for seeding database data.